# display different text by checking null or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql database. I have a database lms_system with table supplier_details. How can i query to display the supplier id, supplier name and contact, If phone number is null then display ‘No’ else display ‘Yes’ with alias name “PHONENUMAVAILABLE”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do that

```
SELECT id, name, contact, IF(phone IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes') phonenumavailable
  FROM supplier_details
```

or

```
SELECT id, name, contact, CASE WHEN phone IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END phonenumavailable
  FROM supplier_details
```

or

```
SELECT id, name, contact, ELT((phone IS NULL) + 1, 'Yes', 'No') phonenumavailable
  FROM supplier_details
```

or

```
SELECT id, name, contact, COALESCE(REPLACE(phone, phone, 'Yes'), 'No') phonenumavailable
  FROM supplier_details
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be3c4/4)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       ......
        , IF(phone_number is null, 'NO', 'YES') 
FROM  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [Your Others Columns],
IF(PHONENUMAVAILABLE IS NULL,'NO','YES') 
[Your Table Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html))

```
SELECT ... IF(`your_field` IS NULL,'NO','YES) as PHONENUMAVAILABLE ... FROM...
```

Or use `CASE` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html))

```
SELECT ...
    CASE WHEN `your_field` IS NOT NULL 
           THEN 'YES'
           ELSE 'NO'
    END AS PHONENUMAVAILABLE
FROM ...
```

There is also an `IFNULL()` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html))

```
SELECT ... IFNULL(`your_field`, 'NO') as PHONENUMAVAILABLE ... FROM ...
```

But that won't return YES if `your_field` is not null